# Why css text color property naming was defined as 'color' and not 'text-color'?

Tags: css

Question is straight forward, the css 'color' property is not intuitive IMHO, it could stand for color about just anything until you figure it is for text.

So we have to use this:

```
foo{ color:happy; }
```

instead of

```
foo{ text-color: superhappy; }
```

Needless to say that those color names don't exist, however my point is that there are text-* properties out there i.e text-decoration

So was this property named as such due to some historical context, programming reason or any other?

Comment: While this is an interesting question I am not sure if it is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @RaulSauco I had the same doubt, to me it was SO meta or here. It can always be re-posted where needed be if not duplicate.

Comment: @RaulSauco Fair enough, i'll take that solution, however  I must say that while checking the options offered this font-color question was not offered or my sight bypassed it due to not having keyword text-color. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because colour can be applied to more than just font. if they did it how your suggesting they would need `text-color` `border-color` and more options and it would get very confusing and long winded so they kept it simple.

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: There already is a [`border-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) property..

Comment: `border: 1px solid currentColor` is what you are looking for

Comment: ?? You do realise if `border-color` is not specified the border will become the color of the text. Read the CSS spec on why color is used. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/